# How to mount to an existing EFS using Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

Currently, I have a json that will create a EFS in an auto scaling group. However, how can I make it so it mounts an existing EFS that is previously created (so i can pre-load data)

this is the current set up

```
"FileSystem": {
  "Type": "AWS::EFS::FileSystem",
  "Properties": {
    "PerformanceMode": "generalPurpose",
    "FileSystemTags": [
      {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": { "Ref" : "VolumeName" }
      }
    ]
  }
},
"MountTarget": {
  "Type": "AWS::EFS::MountTarget",
  "Properties": {
    "FileSystemId": { "Ref": "FileSystem" },
    "SubnetId": { "Ref": "Subnet" },
    "SecurityGroups": [ { "Ref": "MountTargetSecurityGroup" } ]        
  }
},
```

"

Comment: Please add more informaiton on what you want to achieve. You can not 'create an EFS in an auto scaling group'. Are your perhaps trying to mount an EFS on a EC2 instance?